# DynamoDB Queries Significantly slower with .NET Core than with .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-dynamodb, .net-core

I recently converted an WebAPI project running in AWS from .net 4.5 to .net core. Performance went down, and when I looked in to why I discovered the calls to DynamoDB were returning slower than they used to. The app performs a large number of queries in a loop, so the downgrade in performance was noticeable.

I ran the following sample code on both a .net 4.5 and a .net core app on a t1.micro. Both apps where built with release configuration.

```
var times = new List<long>();
foreach(var id in idsToFetch)
{
    var values = new List<object> { value1, value2 };
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    AsyncSearch<Thing> query = _dynamo.DbContext.QueryAsync<Thing>(id, QueryOperator.Between, values);
    var temp = query.GetRemainingAsync().Result;
    watch.Stop();
    times.Add(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
_logger.LogDebug("average query time: " + times.Average());
```

This code runs a series of queries against DynamoDB and then prints out the average time of each query.

I ran this many times. A sample of the output is:

.NET Core:

```
average query time: 5.28125
average query time: 5.515625
average query time: 5.109375
average query time: 5.359375
average query time: 5.484375
```

.NET 4.5:

```
average query time: 2.65625
average query time: 3.15625
average query time: 2.28125
average query time: 2.296875
average query time: 3.1875
```

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know why this is happening? Is it an issue with the AWS DynamoDB .net core nuget package or something more fundamental to .net core?
2. Does anyone have any idea what I can do to mitigate this?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably may create an issue in `AWS Dynamo for .Net Core` repository

Comment: Have you tried to use AWS ip instead of domain name? If you have an improvement in your performance, then you have something not working very well in your local network.